# What exactly is .params and what does it do?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently working my way through Learning jQuery 4th edition, where i am given an example of a form which accepts one text input.The form, when submitted, searches through the jQuery docs for the string inputted, retrieves it as a JSONP object and displays it.

In the example, i am given the following code extract

```
//more code

  var buildItem = function(item) {
    var title = item.name,
        args = [],
        output = '<li>';

    if (item.type == 'method' || !item.type) {
      if (item.signatures[0].params) {
        $.each(item.signatures[0].params, function(index, val) {
          args.push(val.name);
        });
      }
      title = (/^jQuery|deferred/).test(title) ? title : '.' + title;
      title += '(' + args.join(', ') + ')';
    } else if (item.type == 'selector') {
      title += ' selector';
    }
    output += '<h3><a href="' + item.url + '">' + title + '</a></h3>';
    output += '<div>' + item.desc + '</div>';
    output += '</li>';

    return output;
  };

//more code
```

i am having trouble understanding the line

```
 $.each(item.signatures[0].params, function(index, val) {
              args.push(val.name);
            });
```

specifically what does .params actually do? I understand that it is accessing .params from within the signatures in the object returned, but i do not see any .params in the returned object, nor can i seem to find any documentation on .params ..

Any help would be appreciated.

jsFiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/QPR4Z/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the value in `signatures[0]` - note that it is **arbitrary data** from a JSON request [for the jQuery API documentation]. That is, ".params" doesn't do anything, except function as *normal* property access. Despite syntax highlighting, it is *not* a reserved word and has *no* special meaning.

---

Here is some relevant extracted JSON to illustrate the point:

```
"signatures":[
  { //  <-- i.e. signatures[0]
    "added":"1.8",
    "params":[    // <-- property called "params", which represents an array
                  //     of objects that describe the given parameter
      {"name":"selector","type":"Selector",..}
    ],
    ..
  },
  ..
]
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment, just to reiterate, am i right in saying that the "params" is functions like a general placeholder to access the __proto__ object that is returned?

Comment: @Kenneth.J It's not a function, it's just the name of a property, like "added" or "value" or "type".