# What is arbitrary data/JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've recently come across the term arbitrary data/ arbitrary json and i can't seem to understand what exactly is it and/or find any documentation on it. I know that JSON is a format for sending data over the internet, so how exactly can a format be arbitrary?

EDIT::

//more code

```
  var buildItem = function(item) {
    var title = item.name,
        args = [],
        output = '<li>';

    if (item.type == 'method' || !item.type) {
      if (item.signatures[0].params) {
        $.each(item.signatures[0].params, function(index, val) {
          args.push(val.name);
        });
      }
      title = (/^jQuery|deferred/).test(title) ? title : '.' + title;
      title += '(' + args.join(', ') + ')';
    } else if (item.type == 'selector') {
      title += ' selector';
    }
    output += '<h3><a href="' + item.url + '">' + title + '</a></h3>';
    output += '<div>' + item.desc + '</div>';
    output += '</li>';

    return output;
  };

//more code
```

in the example code above, i am told that the .params is **arbitrary data** from a JSON request [for the jQuery API documentation].

What then is arbitrary data?

Would really appreciate any answers and/or clarifications.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QPR4Z/2/

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it just means "dummy", "trivial"... A reference would be nice.

Comment: @elclanrs i've added some additional code if you would care to look at it.

Comment: Where does this code come from ? You say "you are told", by whom ?

Comment: @Zoyd The code comes from an example in the book learning jQuery 4th edition, where i was told that it is arbitrary from another question of mine here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23404444/what-exactly-is-params-and-what-does-it-do

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the English language, not programming.

Comment: @JezenThomas Many English words have a different or specific meaning in the area of computing, it just turns out this one doesn't but the OP didn't know it. Since billions (literally) of people are not native English speakers (including myself), it would be tough for them not to accept this kind of questions on SO.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> **arbitrary** |ˈärbiˌtrerē|
>   adjective
>
> based on random choice or personal whim, rather than any reason or
>   system: *his mealtimes were entirely arbitrary.*
>
> - Mathematics: (of a constant or other quantity) of unspecified value.

It just means there could be any value in there. This is opposed to a specification that says something like *"this array always contains X, Y and Z"*. Arbitrary values in contrast say *"we're sending you **something** in this array, but we can't really tell you in advance what exactly that is."* If you're told that you can *send* arbitrary data yourself, it means you can send anything you want, it doesn't have to follow any particular format.

Note that this is all about the data contained in the JSON format, not about the JSON format itself.

Comment: thanks for a very detailed answer. However wouldnt this mean that every and any json data returned to me from a request would therefore be arbitrary, if it isn't from something standardised (e.g a plugin, etc? )?

Comment: There are several levels of "standardised" here. JSON is a very specific standard about the way data structures can be expressed as strings. However, these *data structures* that JSON can express are entirely arbitrary. That means JSON doesn't prescribe what content you can or cannot send in it. Based on that a particular service usually has a specified data structure; i.e. the service standardised for itself that it's always going to send you *X* in array key *Y*. If that service tells you "key Z contains arbitrary data", then that could be anything.

Answer (score 3):

It means "Some organisation of the data structure (including names of properties) that was just made up by some person" rather than being an established standard.

The data structure is arbitrary. It is expressed in the JSON standard (which isn't).